# How can I check out file with p4 on TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, perforce

So far I have this command:

`p4 -p port:host -u user -P password edit -c default C:\tc\1890hagn\text.txt`

However it responds with `Client 'MYMACHINE' unknown - use 'client' command to create it.` How can I fix that? I have to run this checkout command on TeamCity and ideally I would use TeamCity's perforce session.

(port, host, user, password, C:\tc\1890hagn\text.txt and MYMACHINE are only dummy names for the question)

Comment: Why do you say it would be ideal to use TeamCity's Perforce workspace for this edit operation? Will you also be submitting the file? Or always reverting it after you change it? What sort of changes do you need to make to 'text.txt'?

Comment: Thanks for the question Bryan! I do text replacements within the file and revert it at the end. Also, due to legacy reasons we might want to awfully submit the executables to perforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a VCS root defined that covers your depot area?

You say you want to use TeamCity's Perforce workspace, hence you need to have a VCS root. I think TeamCity names its clients something like `TC_p4_MYMACHINE_a91128fb222f8594_282888d26bc0a9d1` (rather than plain `MYMACHINE`) and it uses `%P4CLIENT%` (the environment variable) to tell Perforce that it wants to work within this client. Run a build, then switch to the *Parameters* tab of the build and see what the value of `env.P4CLIENT` was.

I think that if `env.P4CLIENT`/`%P4CLIENT%` is defined, then your `p4.exe` command-line should pick the value up. (Though what you describe suggests the opposite: the fact that `p4.exe` is trying to use `MYMACHINE` suggests that it doesn't see `P4CLIENT`; I believe the hostname is Perforce's default client name.) If `env.P4CLIENT` is absent, chances are you haven't set up a VCS root.

A side note: using TeamCity's workspace may seem convenient (the alternative of having to create a workspace of your own seems elaborate) but has a downside: if your build breaks half-way through, you'll leave a pending changelist with a checked-out file in TeamCity's workspace. Then, when TeamCity tries to clean that workspace up (it does so from time to time) it will report a problem because it can't delete a workspace which has opened files in it.

Comment: I have a VCS root defined, still I couldn't find env.P4CLIENT set :(

Comment: In your VCS Root settings, are you specifying the client as (a) Stream, (b) Client, or (c) Client mapping?